# Even with IFS defined can't move the file with double space

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, find, ifs

When I cat the file which I've generated with this:

```
IFS=$'\n'
while read i
        do printf "%s " "$i"
        stat --format=%Z $i
done < <(/bin/find /data/owncloud/*/files -type f -not -path "/data/owncloud/sds/*" -not -name "ownCloud Manual.pdf") > /root/script/newpurge/filelistwithchangeddate
```

There is a line like this:

```
/data/owncloud/ksdfl/files/GIA - AGP/12 Samples/738617 sdds Hotel/Thumbs.db
```

However if I list this file it actually has 2 spaces in the name like this:

```
/data/owncloud/ksdfl/files/GIA\ -\ AGP/12\ Samples/738617\ \ sdds\ Hotel/Thumbs.db
```

And when the move/delete part is running it doesn't move these files with double spaces. This is the rest part of the script:

```
# epoch date 30 days earlier than today
filetodelete=$(expr `date +'%s'` - 2592000)

# Files older than 30 days
/bin/awk -v epoch="$filetodelete" '$NF<epoch' /root/script/newpurge/filelistwithchangeddate > /root/script/newpurge/oldfiles

/bin/awk '{$NF=""}1' /root/script/newpurge/oldfiles > /root/script/newpurge/marktodelete

sed -i "s/[ ]\+$//g" /root/script/newpurge/marktodelete

today=$(date +%Y%m%d)
mkdir /data/willbedeleted/$today
cp -pr /root/script/newpurge/marktodelete /data/willbedeleted/$today/


while IFS= read -r i; do
    mv -- "$i" /data/willbedeleted/$today/
done < /root/script/newpurge/marktodelete
```

Where is the issue?

Comment: Can you please create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: As an alternative to using spaces to separate filename vs timestamp, consider another sepator (e.g., ':'). It will simplify processing, and remove some steps.